# What is the proper way to use websockets in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, real-time

I have an app that reads from firebase and if I post to the database and then refresh, I see the new results. The problem is, it's a chat app so I don't want to refresh all the time and when someone else posts they should be able to see that in real time.

I was using this for a bit:

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
    setInterval(this.getMessagesAndSetState, 3000);
  }
```

But this is heavy and results in a slow laggy browser (although it does basically achieve what I want)

Does firebase have a method that will constantly update in real time if called?
Or does it integrate well with websockets?

Answer (score 1):

firebase triggers events called value which will be called if there is anything changed on the server

example below

```
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  updateStarCount(postElement, snapshot.val());
});
```

ref
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

if you are making this app in angularjs then you can use libraries like angularfire which will add the three way binding to your app

Comment: im using react. so calling that `on` method should update my code in real time?